# Pandas DataFrame not updating CSV: append() vs .loc and function file placement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file

I've encountered a peculiar issue with pandas and how it behaves when updating DataFrames based on the method used (`append()` vs `.loc`) and where functions are placed (in the same file vs separate files).

### Background:

I am familiar with the fact that the `append()` method in pandas returns a new DataFrame. As a result, when you use `append()`, you essentially reassign the variable in the local scope to this new DataFrame, leaving the global variable unchanged. This is why the `.loc` method, which modifies the DataFrame in place, can be used to avoid this reassignment issue.

#### Scenario 1 (Feedbacks):

- Loaded feedbacks from a CSV into a `feedbacks` DataFrame.
- Appended new feedback using `feedbacks = feedbacks.append(new_data)`.
- T**he CSV wasn't updated with the new feedback. (expected)**
- The functions handling feedbacks (e.g., `update_feedbacks()`) were located in a separate file from the main logic.
- When I changed the method to use .loc instead of append(), the CSV updated correctly.(expected)

#### Scenario 2 (Users):

- Loaded users from another CSV into a `users` DataFrame.
- Appended a new user using `users = users.append(new_data)`.
- **The CSV was correctly updated with the new user. (unexpected)**
- **All user-related functions and logic were in the same file.**

### Question:

I'm perplexed by the second scenario. Even though I used the append() method, which should create a new DataFrame and reassign the local variable, the CSV updated correctly. The only apparent difference between the two scenarios is the placement of functions (same file vs separate files).

Does the placement of functions in separate files vs. a single file affect how pandas behaves with respect to DataFrame reassignment? If so, why? Any clarifications on this unexpected behavior would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

Here's a simplified version of my code for feedbacks:

```py
# main.py
from utils import *

def rate_and_feedback_product(username):
    global feedbacks
    ...
    feedback = { ... }
    feedbacks = feedbacks.append(feedback, ignore_index=True)
    print(feedbacks)
    update_feedbacks()

# utils.py
def load_data_from_pandas(filename):
    filepath = f'{DATA_DIR}/{filename}'
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        return pd.read_csv(filepath)
    else:
        print(f"The path '{filepath}' does not exist!")

feedbacks = load_data_from_pandas('feedbacks.csv')

def update_feedbacks():
    global feedbacks
    ...
    save_data_to_pandas('feedbacks.csv', feedbacks)
```

And for users:

```py
def add_user():
    global users
    ...
    user = { ... }
    users = users.append(user, ignore_index=True)
    update_users()

def update_users():
    global users
    ...
    save_user('users.csv', users)
```